# Clipboard content missed after screen is locked and unlocked

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen, clipboard, unlock

Steps to reproduce:

- Copy a ***text*** in your clipboard
- Lock the screen (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- Login again
- Try to Paste the ***text*** and it cannot be restored.

Note that I did't have this problem with my Ubuntu 15.10.

After installing a fresh 20.04, I saw the issue.

Comment: Same issue in ubuntu 22.04